# SPARQL: how to also SELECT the Object that I inspect as a result of the query

Tags: sparql, rdf

Here a SPARQL query:

```
PREFIX : <...#>

SELECT *
WHERE { {  :Airspace_LSAGE_411 ?p ?o . }
UNION {  :Airspace_LSAGN_411 ?p ?o . }
UNION {  :Airspace_LSAGS_411 ?p ?o . }
}  LIMIT 2000
```

This will get me the properties and associated values of the three airspace-objects `Airspace_LSAGE_411`, `Airspace_LSAGN_411`, `Airspace_LSAGS_411`.

The Problem is that in the result table, I only have the columns `p` and `o`. So I do not know which row belongs to which airspace, for example:

```
p       o
----    ----
:color  red
:color  blue
```

Is it possible to repeat the airspace name in the result to get something like this:

```
s                     p       o
----                  ----    ----
Airspace_LSAGE_411    color  red
Airspace_LSAGN_411    color  blue
```

I know that differentiation should be easy by doing three queries, one after the another, but my main point is how to get complete triples as a result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [VALUES](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#inline-data) to provide the data inline.

```
SELECT  ?s ?p ?o
{VALUES ?s { :Airspace_LSAGE_411 :Airspace_LSAGN_411 :Airspace_LSAGS_411}
?s ?p ?o. }
```

Comment: works. I also learned that the WHERE keyword is obviously not required.

Comment: I think it's only optional when using a basic graph pattern.